# Is there a limit to how many hosts a Eucharistic Minister is permitted to carry in one day?

Tags: biblical-basis, communion, ecclesiology

A minister at my church insists that we are only permitted to carry up to 3 hosts at a time. Is there any regulation on this?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Which denomination are you asking about? Please [edit] this to clarify.